# Can´t use Old version of Crates in Rust

Tags: rust, rust-cargo, rust-crates

due to my Uni project i need to fuzz some crates and recreate bugs. But for some reason when i choose the version `bson="1.2.0"` and do `Cargo update`  i find this version in my Cargo.lock  `[[package]] name = "bson" version = "1.2.4"`

Can some one help me with that please?

removing Cargo.lock and reinstall, but no help

Comment: https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/reference/specifying-dependencies.html

Comment: Tldr: specify version as `bson="^1.2.0" `

Comment: did not work still uses the version 1.2.0 :/

Comment: fixed it it is the bson="=1.2.0", thank you for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`cargo update` means to choose the *latest* compatible version for all dependencies. You have two choices:

- Make an exact version requirement:

  ```ini
  [dependencies]
  bson = "=1.2.0"
  ```
- Ask to update the `Cargo.lock` selected version to a specific version:

  `cargo update -p bson --precise 1.2.0`

  This would be overwritten the next time you run `cargo update`, but it might be easier for quick experiments and, in general, if you want to reproduce an old build, then the best way to do that is to use the old `Cargo.lock` data.